# c++: which functions gives the sum of an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, sum

I'm looking for a function in C++, to return the summation over all elements of an array, similar to what we have in Matlab, i.e., sum(A), where A is an array. 
I know one can simply do a for loop, but isn't there any function doing so, for example in "std::"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sum of consecutive elements in an array, C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108622/sum-of-consecutive-elements-in-an-array-c)

Comment: @JeromeL I am pretty damn sure it's not a duplicate (of that particular Q at least)

Answer (score 12):

The function is called [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate), and resides in [`<numeric>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/numeric).

It works with both Standard Library containers (which are able to provide an `InputIterator`, so pretty much every one of them) and C-style arrays - provided you use `std::begin` and `std::end`. Otherwise `container.begin()/end()` are of course fine; refer to the example use for more information.

One thing to note that it is provided with two overloads, one of them adding a `BinaryOperation`. It defaults to `std::plus` in the other version. What this means in practice is that it becomes a `fold` or `reduce` from other languages.

---

An example using C-style arrays, provided by **@BoBTFish** - [**ideone link**](http://ideone.com/JeU0mi).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
    int nums[] = {1,5,3,2,7,8,100,3};
    std::cout
        << std::accumulate(std::begin(nums),
                           std::end(nums),
                           0)
        << '\n';
}
```

Comment: "Specialized for C-style arrays"? [Where?](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate). Do you mean that `std::begin` and `std::end` are?

Comment: @BoBTFish Hm, you're kinda right. Since `accumulate` uses `std::begin/end` it uses *its* specialization. I'll clear this up. That being said, specializations are a part of implementation, not the signature presented (which doesn't make my original statement any less wrong).

Comment: `std::accumulate` doesn't use `std::begin/end`, although you most likely use them when calling it. Unless you are referring to some upcoming range version, which isn't standard yet?

Comment: @BoBTFish Yeah, thinking in ranges is something you hardly give up :). You're of course right, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @BoBTFish I'll copy the source into the answer, I hope you don't mind.